# Non-volatile Evaluate

Tags: vba

I have a worksheet containing all the equations. In other sheet I would like to calculate function value for different variables. Let's say in Sheet2 cell A1 I have the formula `=125*B1^2+20*B1+222`. In Sheet1 cell A10 I have `=eval(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(Sheet2!A1),"*B1","*"&CELL("address",C10)))`, so basically I change value of variable with different in cell C10.

My eval function is:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

The problem is that it takes forever to calculate and I would like to achieve same results without Volatile option, but have no idea how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a custom `Eval` function, use the [secret, built in `EVALUATE` function](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function) left over from Excel 4.0

Create named range, called something like "EvaluatedFormula", and set the "Refers to:" to `=EVALUATE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(Sheet2!$A$1),"B1","C" & ROW()))`

Then, in cell A10, you just type `=EvaluatedFormula`, and BOOM! It's done.  This can calculate over 9,000 rows in a fraction of a second - *much* faster than your `Eval` UDF

Comment: Thanks! That idea is great and works much better. But how can I make my variable "dynamic"? Here is issue I'm dealing with right now - my old formula was: `eval(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(INDEX(MATERIALS!$A$2:$I$30,MATCH($F$8,MATERIALS!$A$2:$A$30,0),5)),"*N4","*"&CELL("address",S48))))` Basically I want to look for a specific string and match it with lookup region for specific formula. The question is what should be my name range it such case?

Comment: @Kris The *simplest* option is to have a Working column to calculate your Formula, and let your Named Range look at that (e.g. select cell B1, and create `=EVALUATE(A1)` so that it takes the text from the cell on the left and evaluates that) - see how the code inside `=EVALUATE(..)` is mostly the code that you wrote in `eval`?  Just remember to include Sheet Names (`Sheet2!$C3`) - since relative references move with the cell, fill-down is fairly simple

Comment: sorry maybe I was not clear when explaining my issue for the first time. I edited my previous comment to be more precise to show my real issue I'm dealing with. Thank you and sorry for not being enough clear

Comment: @Kris Select one of your cells that has an `=eval()` formula in, copy that formula and - with the cell **still selected**, create your named range with that formula (but change `eval(` to `EVALUATE(`) - it *should* work absolutely fine.

Comment: It works until I don't change reference string in cell F8 which then should be found in lookup table. Hard to explain with words, can I somehow upload worksheet with example?

Comment: Actually it works until no other formula is used before `EVALUATE()` i.e. if not used inside IF() formula
Anyway it's a huge improvement. Many thanks, that saves me a lot of headache!